# QDialog without tab in task bar

Tags: windows, qt, qdialog, qmessagebox

The question is very simple. Is it possible to show `QDialog` or `QMessageBox` without creating a tab in the task bar for it? I tried using exec(), show(), changing value of modal, but the tab is always on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify parent window for the `QMessageBox`:

```
QApplication a(argc, argv);
qt_test_dialog w;
w.show();
// with additional button
// QMessageBox box(QMessageBox::Information, "Title", "Hello there!", QMessageBox::Ok);

// without additional button!
QMessageBox box(QMessageBox::Information, "Title", "Hello there!", QMessageBox::Ok, &w);
```

Or simply:

```
QMessageBox box(&w);
box.setText("Hello");
box.exec();
```

Note that parent parameter can even be empty `QWidget`:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    // plain wrong (you will not be able to exit application) - but it demonstrates 
    // the case
    QMessageBox box(new QWidget());
    box.setText("Hello");
    box.exec();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: And what must qt_test_dialog be? just a custom QWidget? Can you please explain it in a little bit more detail?

Comment: @AndreyChernukha Chernukha In my case, this is a simple QMainWindow subclass (generated from wizard), but it can be custom QWidget, etc.